# How to set a constant 'state' variable using hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Let's say I have some state variable `width`, and I know it will never change, but I need to run some computations on it based on a prop I receive. I don't want to do it in the body of the function, as it will run on every re-render. So:

```
const SOME_CONSTANT_NUMBER = 50;

const someFunc = ({multiplier: number}) => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(SOME_CONSTANT_NUMBER * multiplier);

  return (
    <div>
      {width}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Now I've also instantiated a function `setWidth` that I will never use.

I could use a hook to run only on mount, but that's more code and not necessary.

```
const SOME_CONSTANT_NUMBER = 50;

const someFunc = ({multiplier: number}) => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);

  useHook(() => {
    const updatedWidth = SOME_CONSTANT_NUMBER * multiplier;
    setWidth(updatedWidth);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {width}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I think the worst approach would be below, as it will calculate it on every rerender:

```
const SOME_CONSTANT_NUMBER = 50;

const someFunc = ({multiplier: number}) => {
  const width = SOME_CONSTANT_NUMBER * multiplier;
  return (
    <div>
      {width}
    </div>
  );
}
```

*Note this example is simple, but assume there are much more props, and that the computation for this `width` is computationally heavy.

Comment: If you need to run calculations with the new props, then you're going to have to recalculate, isn't that the point?

Comment: Sort of just how hooks work, unless you're looking to memoize and then there will still need to be checks for if the multiplier changed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) for exactly that usecase.

```
 const width = useMemo(() => SOME_CONSTANT_NUMBER * multiplier, [multiplier]);
```

Note that `useMemo` itself comes with a cost (it's another function) so you should use it only if you know that calculating the value is *really costly* meaning: causes lags (if not you should really check performance, and wether `useMemo` increases it).

Comment: Hmmm, so what if it's iterating over a relatively short array, let's say under 20, and manipulating it slightly to return a new array? If `useMemo` is too costly for this case, what is the suggested approach not to re-calculate on rerenders?

Comment: ⚠ Attention! This answer may be misleading. From the useRef docs: "You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, not as a semantic guarantee. In the future, React may choose to “forget” some previously memoized values and recalculate them on next render [...]". I came looking for a guaranteed stable value, because that's what the question seems to be asking for, but useMemo is *not* it. i.e. If your code works exactly the same with and without useMemo you're good, otherwise you're using it wrong.

Comment: as per according to the docs: "Write your code so that it still works without useMemo — and then add it to optimize performance."
Any idea to write the code if useMemo is no longer working in future React?
Using exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to serailize it on the state, but let's follow your approach:

```
const MY_RATIO = 3
const SomeComponent = ({value}) =>{
    const [state, setter] = useState(value * MY_RATIO)
    useEffect(() =>{
        setter(value * MY_RATIO)
    }, [value, MY_RATIO])
}
```

Now you are only updating the state when your prop `value` changes. But a better approach would be to use `useMemo`

```
const memoizedValue = useMemo(() => MY_RATIO * value, [MY_RATIO, value])
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you should be using the useMemo hook https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

```
    const width = useMemo(() => SOME_CONSTANT_NUMBER * multiplier , [multiplier])
```

Comment: reason for downvote as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56298308/how-to-set-a-constant-state-variable-using-hooks#comment114155569_56298419

Comment: the solution could be improved if it follows as the guideline in docs "Write your code so that it still works without useMemo — and then add it to optimize performance."

Comment: Hi @AizzatSuhardi Thanks for the comment. If you look at my answer, I think you will find it will work exactly the same with or without useMemo and is exactly the intended use case for this hook. The question was about optimizing performance for a computationally expensive calculation. `const width = SOME_CONSTANT_NUMBER * multiplier` will work exactly the same as wrapping it in a memo, but will prevent it from recalculating on every render. I made no guarantee that the value will never be recalculated, but it will be memoized in most normal scenarios.

Comment: Of course, as stated in the question, it's obviously not useful for this example, it was a contrived example in order to ask the question. useMemo should only be used for computationally expensive values.